# Resolve error when migrating a FlashBuilder project to FDT

Tags: apache-flex, fdt

I'm migrating a FlashBuilder project (actually a project I'm working on with FlexBuilder eclipse plugin on Linux) to use FDT. I managed to import the project, and make it aware of other projects it depends on.

However I get lots of compile errors for things that seem harmless (and used to compile). At least, for example :

```
<mx:SomeClass initialize="{this.init()}" ... >
   <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
         ....
        public function init() : void {
          // ... whatever
        }

        public function foo(event : Event) : void {
          // .. whatever
        }
            ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:SomeOtherComponent click="{this.foo(event)}"/>
 ... etc ....
```

So, I get "unresolved function" for all the calls of the form someAttribute="{this.someFunction()}", even though the function is described in the same block file.

Is it that I've been abusing AS3 / FlashBuilder for all this time ?

Also, generic components have problem. Assume I have a class with a deferred 'content' attribute, and I want to instanciate this class and "fill the blank" :

I define a custom component in a CustomComponent.mxml file, with a deferred content

```
<mx:VBox>
 <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      public var content : IDeferredInstance;

      public function buildMe() : void {
         this.addChild(content.getInstance() as UIComponent);
      }
```

I extend the custom component in another xml file, putting something as the content (namespace is just the name of the namespace that contains the CustomComponent file)

```
 <namespace:CustomComponent xmln:namespace="..." >
   <namespace:content >
        <!-- Whatever ... -->
   </namespace:content >
 </namespace:SomeClassWithDeferredInstance >
```

Then again, I get an "Can't resolve 'content'" error in the second file (at the line that reads namespace:content).

Things to mention :

- I'm using FDT 4.0, under Linux, with a (valid) eval key
- I'm using a custom Flex 3.5 SDK (not one shipped with FDT, but not a too strange one either)

Hoping anyone can help ...

Thanks

PH

Comment: Flash Builder and FDT use the same Flex Compiler (Adobe's Open Source one).  I'd usually recommend checking the version of your SDK/Compiler, however if you're using a custom SDK, I assume you've already done that. I don't understand your 'deferred content' attribute explanation.

Comment: I think I meant "custom component", as described here : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=intro_2.html (I added an example)

Answer (score 0):

If it compiles correctly, and without any compiler warnings, then it's a bug in the parser and not in your code. Please file it in JIRA: http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT

For me, this bit of code does not have any error flags - I even get quick assists to help me generate code.

Your FDT version might be incorrect as well. You're using 4.0 and that is quite old (about a year). Since then many features have been added and bugs fixed.  See the release notes for more.

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_4_Release_Notes

I suggest upgrading to FDT 4.5.X

```
    <s:ApplicationminWidth="955" minHeight="600" initialize="{this.init();}">
    <fx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
            private function init() : void {}
            private function foo(event : MouseEvent) : void {}
       ]]>
       </fx:Script>
       <s:Button click="this.foo(event);"/>
    </s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my defense, I posted the question 9 months ago, so 4.0 was pretty fresh at this time ;) I'm not gonna have a chance to test FDT4.5 any time soon, though ...